# ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType

Tags: docker

estoy creando un docker-compose.yml, no veo problema en el archivo pero cada vez que ejecuto el --build despliega el error "setup this up without issue"

```
version: '3.3'

services:

web1:
image: docker_micro
container_name: web1
ports:
- "1000:8080"

web2:
image: docker_micro
container_name: web2
ports:
- "2000:8080"

web3:
image: docker_micro
container_name: web3
ports:
- "3000:8080"

haproxy:
build: ./proxy
container_name: haproxy
ports:
 - "8080:8080"
```

¿cual sera el problema?

Answer (score 1):

El formato de los archivos para Docker Compose usa [YAML](http://yaml.org/), por lo tanto, necesitas identar correctamente el archivo:

```
version: '3.3'

services: 
  web1:
    image: docker_micro
    container_name: web1
    ports:
      - "1000:8080"
  web2:
    image: docker_micro
    container_name: web2
    ports:
      - "2000:8080"    
  web3:
    image: docker_micro
    container_name: web3
    ports:
      - "3000:8080"
  haproxy:
    build: ./proxy
    container_name: haproxy
    ports:
       - "8080:8080"
```

Esto debería bastar para que funcione.